# Fan is starting and then stopping before boot

Tags: hardware-failure, fan, acer-aspire

So I recently re-installed a new laptop motherboard in a acer aspire r3-471T. After I plug everything in and power it on it boots fine except that before the acer logo appears on the screen or f12 or f2 works, the fan turns on at full speed and then stops, and the fan won't start again. Other then that it is absolutely fine. It has a core i5, 2.2ghz, and 8gb ram, 4gb of those are built in. Also, it has no hard drive (I boot from a USB) and the place where the hardrive would plug in is empty because of this. Any ideas?

Comment: How can a “fried motherboard” be absolutely fine?  You will have to find the damaged ICs and replace them

Comment: I meant a new one after I had fried my old one

Comment: Sounds like a short

Comment: The fan won't start after it turns on the first time during the boot. If I reboot it will do the same thing.

Comment: If you do a CPU burn in test does it start? If not, try flashing the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably nothing wrong with your fan cable and connectors since the fan runs briefly in the beginning. If you want to make an effort anyway, re-seat the connectors at both ends of the fan cable.

Look at the BIOS settings to see what is available in the way of fan control, if anything.

The processor likely has a thermometer and can vary the fan speed. If the processor is not hot then it doesn't need to run the fan at a high speed. Perhaps your board was designed not to run the fan at all below a certain processor temperature.